# Get the content of anchors via Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

I have the content of a page (source code) stored inside a variable. Now i need to get some numbers stored inside of some anchors.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('page');
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var html = "<?php echo $homepage; ?>" ;
});
</script>
```

Now i want to filter the source code i stored inside $homepage in order to get the values of some  tags.

The code looks like this:

```
        <table class="tbl">
        <tr  class="odd" >
            <td ><a href="1181">1181 cm</a></td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
            <td ><a href="1182">1182 cm</td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>

        <tr  class="odd" >
            <td ><a href="1183">1183 cm</a></td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
            <td ><a href="1184">1184 cm</a></td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>

        <tr  class="odd" >
            <td ><a href="1185">1185 cm</a></td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
            <td ><a href="1186">1186 cm</a></td>
            <td>8/17/2014</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

I just need some help on what more exactly to search after, what tutorials. I tried most of the already predefined functions on the internet but without succes.

Comment: Have you looked at using DOM parser? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hello @Dan, i managed to solve the problem using the DOM parser you privided. How can i mark your comment as the answer? Also thanks very much :)

Comment: You don't have to mark the comment as the answer, you can upvote the comment and just leave it as is.

Comment: Btw, don't do `var html = "<?php echo $homepage; ?>" ;` .. instead, do: `var html = <?php echo json_encode($homepage); ?>;`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to parse strings (and by easy I mean not using regular expressions) is by using split(). For example:

```
function getNumbers(homepage)
{
    var numbers = new Array();
    var splitA = homepage.split('<a href="');

    for(var i=1;i<splitA.length;i++)
    {
        var splitB = splitA[i].split('"');
        numbers.push(splitB[0]);
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

This function will output the numbers from the anchor tags in an array. They will still be strings, though, so you will have to cast them as integers to use them as actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with **regular expression** in php or Jquery

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php) is function of php that can help you.

[exmaple for JQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

this is exprection for extract value inside the  tag

```
<a.*>(.*)</a>
```

or

```
<a.*>([0-9]* ?cm)<
```

you can test this exprestion in [here](http://regexpal.com/)